# UnicodeDecodeError in Python xlsxwriter library

Tags: python, exception, unicode, export-to-excel, xlsx

I'm trying to write a method to allow the exporting of data from a db to an excel file.  I'm using the XlsxWriter library for this.

This is the main function

```
def user_stats_to_excel():
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('user_stats_test.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    worksheet.write_row(0, 0, UserStats.OUTPUT_ORDER)

    for i, user_stat in enumerate(UserStats.objects.all()):
    worksheet.write_row(i+1, 0, user_stat.output())

workbook.close()
```

and then in my model I have:

```
def output(self, data=None):
    """ return a list that's ready for some csv writing """

    if data:
        self.data = data
    dir_self = dir(self)
    lst = []

    for name in self.O:
        if 'do_' + name in dir_self:
            out = getattr(self, "do_" + name)(name)
            if out is None:
                out = u""
            if isinstance(out, list):
                lst.extend(map(self.safe_encode, out))
            else:
                try:
                    lst.append(out.encode('utf-8'))
                except Exception:
                    lst.append(out)
        else:
            try:
                lst.append(self.data.get(name, "").encode('utf-8'))
            except Exception:
                lst.append(self.data.get(name, ""))

    return lst

def safe_encode(self, data):
    try:
        return data.encode('utf-8')
    except Exception:
        return data
```

As you can see I've put encode everywhere already as this is the usual fix with unicode issues in Python.

My stacktrace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/james/pubfront/riidr/apps/stats/admin.py", line 34, in user_stats_to_excel
workbook.close()
File "/Users/james/pubfront/riidr_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 286, in close
self._store_workbook()
File "/Users/james/pubfront/riidr_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/workbook.py", line 509, in _store_workbook
xml_files = packager._create_package()
File "/Users/james/pubfront/riidr_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/packager.py", line 140, in _create_package
self._write_shared_strings_file()
File "/Users/james/pubfront/riidr_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/packager.py", line 280, in _write_shared_strings_file
sst._assemble_xml_file()
File "/Users/james/pubfront/riidr_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/sharedstrings.py", line 53, in _assemble_xml_file
self._write_sst_strings()
File "/Users/james/pubfront/riidr_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/sharedstrings.py", line 83, in _write_sst_strings
self._write_si(string)
File "/Users/james/pubfront/riidr_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/sharedstrings.py", line 110, in _write_si
self._xml_si_element(string, attributes)
File "/Users/james/pubfront/riidr_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlsxwriter/xmlwriter.py", line 122, in _xml_si_element
self.fh.write("""<si><t%s>%s</t></si>""" % (attr, string))
File "/Users/james/pubfront/riidr_venv/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 688, in write
return self.writer.write(data)
File "/Users/james/pubfront/riidr_venv/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 351, in write
data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm finding this a real hassle to debug as the error is only thrown when workbook.close() is called in user_stats_to_excel, so its going to be difficult to find a user that triggers this issue.  I'm hoping I'm not the only person to have this problem

Comment: Have you got a directive at the top of the file like `# coding: utf-8`? It looks like it's trying to encode the output in ascii on output to the worksheet. [This example](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_unicode_python2.html) seems to work.

Comment: I have `###############################################################################
# _*_ coding: utf-8` at the top of the file which as user_stats_to_excel().  I'd copied it from that link

Comment: The unicode handling rules in XlsxWriter (and Excel) are straingtforward: anything in ASCII or UTF8 is written as expected. Getting your data into those formats can be challenging at times. In this case it looks like some data that isn't ASCII or UTF8 is causing the issue. I'd suggest using a debugger or putting a print in `sharedstring.py` or `xmlwriter.py` at the locations in the stack trace to see what string is causing the issue.

Comment: @jmcnamara you were right, we switched from using .encode() to using django.utils.encoding.force_unicode and then it worked great.  We really like the library, super simple to create excel docs.  Great work!

Answer (score 1):

We started using django utils to handle the encoding: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.encoding

If you're not using django then the kitchen library has similar functions:
https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/api-text-converters.html#kitchen.text.converters.to_bytes

The only other thing we had to do was tell xlsxwriter to treat urls as strings
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/workbook.html#Workbook

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename, {'strings_to_urls': False})
```